# Associate string to declared variable in FORTRAN

Tags: fortran

I have a code that begins like that:

```
PROGRAM EXAMPLE

IMPLICIT NONE
REAL, DIMENSION(:,:), ALLOCATABLE :: A B
```

Now, I want the program to read a txt-file like that:

A
1 2
3 4
B
5 6
7 8

And then allocate the matrix [1 2;3 4] to A, and [5 6;7 8] to B. What I planned to do is to read the txt-file and, when it finds A, somehow refer to the previously declared variable A - and so on with B.

Any idea on how to do that?

Comment: It cannot be done automatically to recognize that string "A" refers to variable A. You have to do that manually.

Comment: That is precisely what I would like to learn how to do :)

Comment: The forth line in your example should read as CHARACTER(LEN=80):: in_as_String. Then read the lines in before SCAN 'ing for whether there is an A or not.

Comment: But if I declare A and B as characters, then how could I assign the numerical values from the text file to them? My idea is to use the txt-file as an input file to be modified by the user, so the program should recognize from it the variables and respective values.